# Lucene french search

Tags: java, lucene, french

I was using lucene indexing/searching and faced a problem. Lucene displays some results for query "word" and some for "l'word". (word is just for an example). I need it to display all mentioned results for any of two these queries.

1. I tried to change StandartAnalyzer to FrenchAnalyzer, but it also doesn't recognize this words as the same.
2. Changing all "l'word" to "word" in the index and in the search string is also not an option. We need original string to be displayed in results.

Comment: Did you apply FrenchAnalyzer both on query and index? Did you reindex? Regarding changing the field, if you go down that road, you can have two fields, a stored non-indexed one that is unchanged, and indexed non-stored that is searched.